# Is there a way to use SourceTree for a GitHub Codespaces repository?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I've always loved using SourceTree for my local development, but now most of my development happens with GitHub Codespaces dev containers (which I access from VS Code). I prefer the SourceTree GUI over the VS Code Git GUIs, so does anyone know how I can connect up my SourceTree to the files within Codespaces?

Comment: Unfortunately, SourceTree does not have native integration with GitHub Codespaces or support for connecting directly to dev containers. SourceTree is primarily designed for local repository management rather than remote development environments like Codespaces.